# How to solve a problem with long list of font-sizes on small monitors in ckeditor5?

Tags: font-size, ckeditor5

I have a long list of font-sizes and there is a display problem on small monitors. How to fix it?
https://prnt.sc/o56jwb

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS which overrides those styles. For example, those can look like this.

```
.ck-fontsize-option .ck-button__label {
    font-size: unset !important;
}
```

If you don't want to use `!important` parameter, the solution will be more tricky. You need to remove or block the execution of [this code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/blob/55084ce60ab127a2aab121571f7b0fd044d81163/src/fontsize/fontsizeui.js#L128). You can modify the plugin and use your custom version or you can write own UI part for it. You can find a rendered element in [`componentFactory`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_componentfactory-ComponentFactory.html) and modify it. You can somehow prevent changing [`labelStyle`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_button_buttonview-ButtonView.html#event-change:labelStyle) of a button, or invent some completely new solution for that suitable for your case.